# Received Invalid RTP payload Dropping at gstreamer side

Tags: android, video, udp, gstreamer, h.264

In android side I'm using DatagramPacket to send video/avc (H264) encoded format video byte array data over data gram socket.
when it is receiving destination side gstreamer pipeline it is giving following error.

**gst_rtp_base_depayload_handle_buffer: warning: Received invalid RTP payload, dropping**

So, what could be the cause. Or where to look for the changes in the code while encoding.

avc encoder reference repository -https://github.com/bytestar/android-h264-stream-demo

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"I'm using DatagramPacket to send video/avc (H264) encoded format video byte array data over data gram socket. "* - no code is shown on how you do this, so it is impossible to point out specific things you are doing wrong. But note that DatagramPacket just means UDP, if you want to use RTP (as the peer expects) you need to add the right RTP framing around the data.

Comment: Thank you for your response @SteffenUllrich. So below repo code took for encoding.

https://github.com/bytestar/android-h264-stream-demo

Answer (score 1):

On transmitter part you should send packet in RTP format :

Here an example using Gstreamer

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=TRUE ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=25/1 ! x264enc key-int-max=25 tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay config-interval=3 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

If you are doing your own implementation you need encapsulate in RTP packet

On Gstreamer side :

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! glimagesink
```

Comment: Is `rtph264depay` actually needed? I would have thought that `decodebin` would handle the parsing etc. of the SDP/RTP.